# How to capture invalid c enum in swift

Tags: c, swift, core-foundation

I use C to cast my over-the-wire payloads, so int to enum conversion in c:

```
typedef CF_ENUM( uint8_t, MyEnum_t ) {
    a = 0
    b = 1
}
...
value = ( MyEnum_t * ) rawValue;
```

Because the value is over-the-wire, the actual raw value can be any uint8_t. It is possible that the `rawValue` is actually not 0 or 1.

Below I have a swift code sample showing setting an enum to an impossible/invalid value and a switch statement handling that value.

```
import Foundation

enum MyEnum: UInt8 {
    case a = 0
    case b = 1
}

let raw: UInt8 = 0b100 // 4
let value: MyEnum = unsafeBitCast(raw, to: MyEnum.self)

switch value {
case .a:
    print("a:", value) // * not reached *
case .b:
    print("b:", value) // "b: \n"
    print("value == .a => \(value == .a)") // "x == .a => true\n"
    print("value == .b => \(value == .b)") // "x == .b => false\n"
}

print(value.rawValue) // "0"
```

With a C raw value of 4, swift sample shows crazy results:

- 4 force casted prints nothing for its value (most likely char 4 or 0, both unprintable)
- 4 switches as MyEnum.b (1)
- 4 compares equally to MyEnum.a (0)
- 4 as MyEnum raw value prints 0 (MyEnum.a)

Is there any way to capture this error in swift? I prefer to not use these odd results to detect the anomaly.